# VueJS to dynamically control the CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

[image]

My use case is something like this,

1. I got the **star rank** from the back-end as a digit(1,2,3,4,5).
2. If it's number 3 I want to color first 3 stars in yellow and reaming to default color.
   How do I achieve this using Vue JS?

This is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span class="demo">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods:{

  }
}
</script>

<style>
.demo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: 6em;
  color:yellow;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `v-for` and some CSS classes, as shown below.

They would iterate `starRank` times creating `filled-star` stars and then iterate `5 - starRank` times creating `not-filled-star` stars.

In the example below, `starRank` is `3` and, as such, three stars will be yellow.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      starRank: 3
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.demo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 6em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
}

.filled-star { color: yellow; }
.not-filled-star { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span class="demo">
      <span v-for="index in starRank" class="filled-star">&#9733;</span><span v-for="index in (5-starRank)" class="not-filled-star">&#9733;</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I was staring at the `index in (5-starRank)` and could't think of how does it work :D Seems like looking at StackOverflow just after waking up is not a good idea :)

Comment: @sarneeh Haha, look at that, I'm actually about to go to sleep! But I do am much better at night, I really only boot after lunch :P